# What is the purpose of the id property of an ObjectId in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The `id` property of a mongoose object is the string representation of its `_id` property, which is an `ObjectId` `obj.id === obj._id.toString()`. However, the `id` property of the `ObjectId` is some other string that I do not understand the meaning `obj.id !== obj._id.id`

Anyway, I would never think to use `obj._id.id` when working with the model itself, but it gets very ugly when you are working with references and compares like this: `obj.reference.toString === referencedObj.id`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to be concerned with operations involving `obj._id.id` in mongoose. What is it you are trying to assert exactly - ObjectId equality?

Comment: Yes, just objectId equality. I have already managed to compare the objectIds properly, but I wanted to ask just to clarify because I looks confusing.